# Using function inside a change event

Tags: jquery

I have a function I would like to call when a select box is changed, but I am having some scope issues:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function showHint(val) {
        if (TypeVal == 'ordertotal') {
            $('.text-hint').html('Use format MIN_PRICE|MAX_PRICE:AMOUNT');
        } else if (TypeVal == 'totalitems') {
            $('.text-hint').html('Use format MIN_ITEMS|MAX_ITEMS:AMOUNT');
        } else {
            $('.text-hint').html('Enter the shipping cost');
        }
    }
    var TypeVal = $('#Type').val();
    showHint(TypeVal);
    $('#Type').on('change', function () {
        var TypeVal = $(this).val();
        showHint(TypeVal);
    });
});
```

How do I get the `showHint` function to be able to be used during the change function?

Comment: Move the declaration for `showHint()` outside of the `document.ready()`

Comment: The above should work..

Comment: What "scope issues" are you having? What errors are you getting? What's happening or not happening?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are already passing the value you need via `val` inside the showHint function

```
function showHint(val) {
    // no need to use TypeVal here as you are passing the value via the function param 'val'
    // keep in mind that 'val' will be the value attribute of the option tag in the select field
    if (val == 'ordertotal') {
        $('.text-hint').html('Use format MIN_PRICE|MAX_PRICE:AMOUNT');
    } else if (val == 'totalitems') {
        $('.text-hint').html('Use format MIN_ITEMS|MAX_ITEMS:AMOUNT');
    } else {
        $('.text-hint').html('Enter the shipping cost');
    }
}

showHint($('#Type').val());
$('#Type').on('change', function () {
    showHint($(this).val());
});
```

You could keep using `TypeVal`, but inside your `change` handler you are setting the value to a `TypeVal` that is scoped to the change handler, not the global scope. If you want to keep using the `TypeVal` var then just remove the `var` declaration in the change handler. This will use the "global" TypeVal variable.

```
var TypeVal = $('#Type').val(); // this is scoped to the $(document).ready(function() {}
showHint(TypeVal);
$('#Type').on('change', function () {
    // var TypeVal = $(this).val(); // this is scoped to the change function
    TypeVal = $(this).val(); // this is the same var in the document ready scope
    showHint(TypeVal);
});
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/nzy8bgk5/